# Freeze Header Row & First Column In Gridview Asp.Net Webform

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

Any suggestion about how to freeze the first row and first column of Gridview?

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TestingGrid.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestingGrid" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Searched a lot in google but nothing works.

Comment: Better make it a table made out of div elements. Then you can fix elements with css: https://divtable.com/generator/

Comment: not possible with asp controls

Comment: @user5377037, no not with a GridView, but with custom code or perhaps a complex Repeater it can be done. But it is more work than just binding data to a GridView.